# Nginx PHP (5.5.1) FPM strange errors

Tags: nginx, php

At the moment I'm experimenting with Nginx.
I got it working using the newest version installed via repo.
Everything works fine with Nginx standalone.
Then I installed PHP 5.5.1 via sources that I can run different versions and not affection the production webserver and php version. (Nginx was running on another port then 80 for testing purposes.)

Everything went fine. Compiled PHP 5.5.1 without errors, installed it, started PHP-FPM and changed the Nginx config to call PHP FPM when needed. My first test website worked perfectly with this version. Then I tried to get running another website I created. I've changed only the document root for that.

Then I got very strange errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apache_request_headers() in [...]
```

Yes, not real an error... So I removed the function to test if the website works then smoothly when removing a function, which isn't available in PHP-FPM/FastCGI Mode.

Then another error showed in the logs when trying again:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''INSERT ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in [...]
```

After commenting out this variable (only for testing) another error occured:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ')' in [...]
```

So I don't know why those 2 errors occured. The first one is of course of the changed system; function not available.

So my main question is: Why is my code causing these errors with PHP 5.5.1 in FPM mode?
The website works perfectly on my local dev server (PHP 5.4 and Apache) and production Server (Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4)...  I have NO code changed (except config files for db etc). So is someone knowing what can cause this issue?

If you need more information, just ask!

**Edit:**

Error 1:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . TABLE . ' 
(name) 
VALUES
("' . $name . '")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name)';
```

Error 2:

```
'TEXT' => text::parse($row['text']),
```

Comment: Ignoring possible differences between PHP 5.5.1 and PHP 4. You're probably getting those errors on your dev environment and they're just being suppressed or logged. Throw in error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true); on your dev environment.

Comment: I'm talking about PHP 5.5.1 and PHP 5.4. Not PHP 4. 

Set error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);. Still nothing. Works perfectly. Everything.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant 5.4. (for some reason I can't edit that comment). There are differences between 5.5 and 5.4. Can you show the code related to the second error?

Comment: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''INSERT ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in [...]" or "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ')' in [...]"?

Comment: What Charles was asking for is to see the actual code, not the error. The problems you've stated all look like code generated errors and nothing to do with FPM itself. If we could see the code, we could probably help a lot more.

Comment: Added both codelines where the 2 errors occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
PHP rebuilt via source and used newest version (5.5.2).